# Can't launch Payara Micro from payara-micro-maven-plugin, getting "unsupported JDK"

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, eclipselink, payara-micro

I put together a sample project to demonstrate the issue I'm having.

https://github.com/johnmanko/payara-micro-plugin-group

Basically, I'm trying to launch my app via payara micro's maven plugin during development.  Here is the `pom.xml` config:

```xml
<plugin>
                <groupId>fish.payara.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>payara-micro-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.4.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <useUberJar>false</useUberJar>
                    <contextRoot>/myapp</contextRoot>
                    <payaraVersion>${version.payara}</payaraVersion>
                    <deployWar>false</deployWar>
                    <artifactItem>
                        <groupId>fish.payara.extras</groupId>
                        <artifactId>payara-micro</artifactId>
                        <version>${version.payara.micro}</version>
                    </artifactItem>
                    <javaCommandLineOptions>
                        <option>
                            <value>-Xdebug</value>
                        </option>
                    </javaCommandLineOptions>
                    <commandLineOptions>
                        <option>
                            <key>--autoBindHttp</key>
                        </option>
                        <option>
                            <key>--nocluster</key>
                        </option>
                        <option>
                            <key>--port</key>
                            <value>8095</value>
                        </option>
                        <option>
                            <key>--prebootcommandfile</key>
                            <value>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/pre-boot-commands.txt</value>
                        </option>
                        <option>
                            <key>--postbootcommandfile</key>
                            <value>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/post-boot-commands.txt</value>
                        </option>
                        <option>
                            <key>--deploy</key>
                            <value>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}</value>
                        </option>
                    </commandLineOptions>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

The result is the following:

```
[2022-05-11T09:54:58.362-0400] [] [SEVERE] [] [org.eclipse.persistence.session./file:/path/to/payara-micro-plugin-group/payara-micro-plugin-example/target/payara-micro-plugin-example-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/WEB-INF/classes/_MyAppPU.metadata] [tid: _ThreadID=1 _ThreadName=main] [timeMillis: 1652277298362] [levelValue: 1000] [[
  The java.lang.Object class was compiled with an unsupported JDK. Report this error to the EclipseLink open source project.
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 8 out of bounds for length 0
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.libraries.asm.ClassReader.readUnsignedShort(ClassReader.java:3573)


[2022-05-11T09:54:58.364-0400] [] [WARNING] [] [org.eclipse.persistence.session./file:/path/to/payara-micro-plugin-group/payara-micro-plugin-example/target/payara-micro-plugin-example-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/WEB-INF/classes/_MyAppPU.metadata] [tid: _ThreadID=1 _ThreadName=main] [timeMillis: 1652277298364] [levelValue: 900] [[
  The java.lang.String class was compiled with an unsupported JDK. Report this error to the EclipseLink open source project.
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 62
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.libraries.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:196)


[2022-05-11T09:54:58.372-0400] [] [WARNING] [] [org.eclipse.persistence.session./file:/path/to/payara-micro-plugin-group/payara-micro-plugin-example/target/payara-micro-plugin-example-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/WEB-INF/classes/_MyAppPU.metadata] [tid: _ThreadID=1 _ThreadName=main] [timeMillis: 1652277298372] [levelValue: 900] [[
  The java.lang.Long class was compiled with an unsupported JDK. Report this error to the EclipseLink open source project.
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 62
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.libraries.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:196)


[2022-05-11T09:54:58.379-0400] [] [WARNING] [] [org.eclipse.persistence.session./file:/path/to/payara-micro-plugin-group/payara-micro-plugin-example/target/payara-micro-plugin-example-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/WEB-INF/classes/_MyAppPU.metadata] [tid: _ThreadID=1 _ThreadName=main] [timeMillis: 1652277298379] [levelValue: 900] [[
  The java.lang.Number class was compiled with an unsupported JDK. Report this error to the EclipseLink open source project.
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 62
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.libraries.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:196)
```

The project is built with JDK 1.8, and maven is started with setting JAVA_HOME to JDK 1.8:

```sh
DATABASE_USER=user \
DATABASE_PASS=password \
DATABASE_NAME=MY_DB_NAME \
DATABASE_SERVER=localhost \
DATABASE_SERVER_PORT=1234 \
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64 \
M2_HOME=/usr/share/maven \
/usr/share/maven/bin/mvn payara-micro:start
```

The system default is Java 18, but I don't see how that can even come into play.  All included application dependencies were compiled with JDK 1.8 or earlier (I checked each one).

Why would it be picking up major version 62?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the cause.  The plugin uses [Apache Toolchain](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-using-toolchains.html) to locate `java`, and it's finding the wrong one (ie, the system one).

One solution is to add the plugin `<javaPath>` option:

```
                <configuration>
                    <useUberJar>false</useUberJar>
                    <contextRoot>/myapp</contextRoot>
                    <payaraVersion>${version.payara}</payaraVersion>
                    <deployWar>false</deployWar>                    
                    <javaPath>/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java</javaPath>
```

Of course, that won't work for devs on other systems like Windows of Mac.

The proper way is configure a `~/.m2/toolchains.xml` file and set up [Toolchain](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-using-toolchains.html) in the pom to use that.

`~/.m2/toolchains.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<toolchains>
    <!-- JDK toolchains -->
    <toolchain>
        <type>jdk</type>
        <provides>
            <version>1.8</version>
            <vendor>openjdk</vendor>
        </provides>
        <configuration>
            <jdkHome>/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64</jdkHome>
        </configuration>
    </toolchain>
    <toolchain>
        <type>jdk</type>
        <provides>
            <version>11</version>
            <vendor>openjdk</vendor>
        </provides>
        <configuration>
            <jdkHome>/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64</jdkHome>
        </configuration>
    </toolchain>
    <toolchain>
        <type>jdk</type>
        <provides>
            <version>18</version>
            <vendor>openjdk</vendor>
        </provides>
        <configuration>
            <jdkHome>/usr/lib/jvm/java-18-openjdk-amd64</jdkHome>
        </configuration>
    </toolchain>
</toolchains>
```

`pom.xml`

```xml
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.10.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-toolchains-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>toolchain</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <toolchains>
                        <jdk>
                            <version>1.8</version>
                            <vendor>openjdk</vendor>
                        </jdk>
                    </toolchains>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>fish.payara.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>payara-micro-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.4.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <useUberJar>false</useUberJar>
                    <contextRoot>/myapp</contextRoot>
                    <payaraVersion>${version.payara}</payaraVersion>
                    <deployWar>false</deployWar>                    
                    <artifactItem>
                        <groupId>fish.payara.extras</groupId>
                        <artifactId>payara-micro</artifactId>
                        <version>${version.payara.micro}</version>
                    </artifactItem>
                    <javaCommandLineOptions>
                        <option>
                            <value>-Xdebug</value>
                        </option>
                    </javaCommandLineOptions>
                    <commandLineOptions>
                        <option>
                            <key>--nocluster</key>
                        </option>
                        <option>
                            <key>--port</key>
                            <value>8095</value>
                        </option>
                        <option>
                            <key>--postbootcommandfile</key>
                            <value>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/post-boot-commands.txt</value>
                        </option>
                        <option>
                            <key>--deploy</key>
                            <value>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}</value>
                        </option>
                    </commandLineOptions>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

Launch using `nbactions.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<actions>
    <action>
        <actionName>CUSTOM-toolchains:toolchain payara-micro:start (with DB)</actionName>
        <displayName>toolchains:toolchain payara-micro:start (with DB)</displayName>
        <goals>
            <goal>toolchains:toolchain</goal>
            <goal>payara-micro:start</goal>
        </goals>
        <properties>
            <Env.DATABASE_USER>user</Env.DATABASE_USER>
            <Env.DATABASE_PASS>password</Env.DATABASE_PASS>
            <Env.DATABASE_NAME>DATABASE</Env.DATABASE_NAME>
            <Env.DATABASE_SERVER>localhost</Env.DATABASE_SERVER>
            <Env.DATABASE_SERVER_PORT>1234</Env.DATABASE_SERVER_PORT>
        </properties>
    </action>
</actions>
```

Launch using commandline:

```
DATABASE_USER=user \
DATABASE_PASS=password \
DATABASE_NAME=MY_DB_NAME \
DATABASE_SERVER=localhost \
DATABASE_SERVER_PORT=1234 \
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64 \
M2_HOME=/usr/share/maven \
/usr/share/maven/bin/mvn toolchains:toolchain payara-micro:start
```